# How to take more fields when grouping

Tags: elasticsearch, group-by

Trying to group data and take all of its fields by the way.

```
GET /testnews/default/_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "from":50,
  "query":{
   "multi_match": {
    "query": "serenay",
    "fields": ["Data.Title", "Data.Description", "Data.Tags.Title", "Data.MentionTitle", "Data.Program.title", "Data.Program.description", "Data.Program.original_title"]

   }
  },
   "sort":[{
     "Data.CreatedAt": {
       "order": "desc"
     },
     "Data.ViewCount": {
       "order": "desc"
     }
   }],
   "aggs": {
    "group_by_state": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Data.Program.title.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I did it, it returns only "Program Title" in the grouped result.
Just like:

```
{
  "key": "Kocamın Ailesi",
  "doc_count": 3
}
```

But I just want it like:

```
{
"key": "Kocamın Ailesi",
"description": "blabla",
"image": "blabla.jpg",
"date": "YYYY-mm-dd",
"doc_count": 3
}
```

just like sql

```
select * from x group by field
```

Comment: Do you write sql query to get all fields in group by query ? I think not, you will select only specific fields which are in group by clause, Otherwise you won't get specific result.

Comment: The sql query you wrote won't work, since you've grouped by a field, you must use aggregation functions (like sum, avg, min, max and count) on other fields to return a single value per group

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the SQL example, to get the behaviour of

```
select a, b, count(*) from x group by a, b
```

you can aggregate on a, then b like this:

```
"aggs": {
    "group_by_a": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "a"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_b": {
             "terms": {
                 "field":"b"
              }
          }
       }
    }
  }
```

But I don't think that is what you're looking for?
If you want the full documents in aggregations you can use the "top_hits" aggregation to select the top n hits within each aggregation:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_state": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Data.Program.title.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "state_top_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              { "Data.CreatedAt": { "order": "desc" } },
              { "Data.ViewCount": { "order": "desc" } }
            ],
            "_source": {
              "includes": [ "key", "description", "image", "date" ]
            },
            "size":  10 //Will show top 10 hits within keyword agg ordered according to the sort
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```